# Android dialogs with navigation

Tags: android, navigation, modal-dialog

What are the best practices to implement popup windows with navigation? Say, on the first popup you have a list of items, clicking on each show details of each item. Clicking back allow to return to the first view. What is the best way to implement this behavior?

I am familiar with custom dialogs, but different views in the dialog and navigation between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use [Android-WizardPager](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-WizardPager). It provides wizard-functionality in an activity.
To make your activity look like a popup window you can use

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

Comment: Thanks dude, didn´t know about wizard project.

Comment: Make sure you also check out some of the forks that offer additional functionality.